# Is Stackoverflow running on a Linux box? and other questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, server

Netcraft.com gives the following details for [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=http://meta.stackoverflow.com)
[image: metastack]
SO is an ASP.NET app so IIS should be the server, since MONO isn't full featured yet.Given that the details for meta.stackoverflow.com match pretty well.

The Netcraft data for [stackoverflow.com](http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=http://stackoverflow.com)
[image: stack]
stackoverflow.com however shows that it runs on Linux with a history of Linux + IIS. (Now [www.stackoverflow.com](http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=http://www.stackoverflow.com) also shows that it runs on Linux, but since it primarily does a 301 to stackoverflow.com, it could run on anything.)
Data for [stackexchange.com](http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=http://stackexchange.com) also shows that it runs on a nginx server on an Unknown OS. While previous history of Win Server 2008 with IIS 7.5 exists.

Now these signatures, I hear, can be easily spoofed(they can also be misleading), but are they and if not can the-powers-that-be give us some insight.

**Update:**
There is also the *minor* issue of netblock ownership. The records differ for SO & SE, but that is off topic for this question.
[image: stackexchange]

**Update 2**
And we recently were told that meta.SO is moving to NYC, the IP as per [ip2location](http://www.ip2location.com/64.34.119.12) says the IP 64.34.119.12 belongs to CHICAGO
[image: ip2location]

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely caused by the load balancer HAProxy which SO uses to manage traffic for the Trilogy in the original data centre. You can read more about it on the blog here:

[Load Balancing Stack Overflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/load-balancing-stack-overflow/)

There is a few articles on the blog covering this for interest sake. Since all requests for any of the Trilogy sites first go through HAProxy running on Linux, it is most likely passing this information back to the site requesting the information, and not on the Windows Servers sitting behind the proxy actually serving the site. You can also read more about the network setup here:

[Stack Overflow Network Configuration](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-network-configuration/)

Comment: thanks a load! :) That also means that SE is not on a load balancer, then why does it say nginx

Comment: @abel. SE runs in a new datacenter in NY and no details have been released on what or how it runs so far. Since the current trilogy is being migrated there over the course of time, I am assuming once it is finished Jeff will reveal all the gory details. I do know however they implement a similar proxy since the NY data-centre is approximately double the size if not bigger of the current SO farm. A quick google reveals that [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/) is also a HTTP Proxy and filter so it is using a similar setup as SO itself.

Comment: I have been seeing nginx for so long. never bothered to google. thank you.